# th:disabled objects in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have a select object that is readonly,

```
<select id="selectInvoiceId" th:field="*{invoice}" th:disabled="${resto.id != null}" >
    <option value="0">PLEASE SELECT AN INVOICE</option>
    <option th:each="invoice : ${invoices}" 
            th:value="${invoice.id}" 
            th:text="${invoice.symbol}">
    </option>
</select>
```

in the controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/save" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveWallet(@Valid @ModelAttribute("wallet") WalletPayload walletPayload, 
    BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ..
}
```

and in the WalletPayload object I have:

```
@NotNull
private Invoice invoice;
```

then I got always an error in the validation because invoice is null, I would like to know if there is a workaround for the readonly objects

I've tried this, but I have still the error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/save" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveWallet(@Valid @ModelAttribute("wallet") WalletPayload walletPayload,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {


        LOG.debug("WalletPayload walletPayload [ " + walletPayload + " ]");

        if (walletPayload.getId() != null) {
            Invoice fakeInvoine = new Invoice("fake-inv");
            fakeInvoice.setId((long)-1);
            walletPayload.setInvoice(fakeInvoice);
        }


        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return serverContextPath + WALLET_LIST_VIEW_NAME;
        }
```

I also tried to use readonly, but it does not appear as an option on the select object

[image]

Comment: What happens if the walletPayload is new and doesn't have an id? Maybe you should always set a fake invoice (only if it is null, obviously). I.e. change `walletPayload.getId()` with `walletPayload.getInvoice()`

Comment: Try it anyway (IDEs are not always confidence). Also you can use plain HTML readonly attribute without th:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should choose to use `readonly` if you want the values be sent while you don't want the user to be able to edit it.

There is a subtle difference between the use of `disabled` and `readonly`

**Comparison**

> - `readonly` items are not editable, but will be sent when once submited.
> - `disabled` items are not editable and are not sent once submited.
> - `readonly` items are focus-able  while `disabled` one are not.

Comment: A little late to this party, but select does not support readonly (use disabled instead). An upvote for the comparison, this is really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach:

When the select element is disabled add a hidden element that sets a fake-invoice to the form so the saveWallet method will get a walletPayload with the non-null fake-invoice.

Comment: Since is an edit, the object is already set, the purpose is avoid the user to change it

Comment: Use readonly instead of disabled (disabled prevents the field to be submited with the form).

Answer (score 0):

If the walletPayload object contains a null invoice set a non-null invoice in the saveWallet method before making the walletPayload persistent.

Maybe you can define an invoice as a "null invoice" (by setting its ID as a negative value or other specific mark) so you can ignore it when it appears later.